# Tell Chrome that this is local URL

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, productivity

Using ctrl+L shortcut I can tell Chrome browser that this is a query for the default search engine. Is there an similar shortcut for URLs?

But entering `mysite.dev` which is a domain set up on my machine looks it up on Google. I want it to open `http://mysite.dev` instead. How to force it?

Answer (score 0):

If the domain ends in com you could type mysite then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to browse to www.mysite.com.

You could also create a search engine by going to chrome://settings/searchEngines and using any shortcut you want, like so.  Then you could just type "my" to go to your site.

[image]